# Algorithm for Node connectivity optimization

Tags: optimization, graph, theory

I have an interesting problem i'm trying to solve. Let me explain the problem first.

A node can assume a role of master or slave.

- The rule of the slave is that, they can connect to only one master.
  Slaves only select masters that are closest to them (lets say x
  meters).
- The master is free to connect to multiple slaves (as long as the
  slaves are < x meters from the master). A master cannot connect to
  another master. A slave cannot connect to another slave. Given a
  arbitrary number of nodes and their locations, the goal is to come up
  with optimal role assignment (master or slave) to each node so that
  the overall connectivity (i.e. number of connections) are increased.

Is there any well researched algorithms for these types of problems?

My initial thoughts to see if i can model this problem as graph theory problem and try to solve.

Any pointers on what algorithms would be applicable for this problem?

Comment: I think that this problem is a bit underspecified - what do you mean by "overall connectivity is increased?" Are you trying to maximize the number of connections?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to maximize the number of connections. Also i forgot to add another constraint, that a master cannot connect to another master.

Comment: I see connections with the "fixed-radius near neighbor search" and "cover" problems: for every node (master candidate), you can find the subset of nodes that are within distance x from it (slave candidates). But the problem gets complicated by the fact that a slave relates to a single master, so that there is competition between the masters to acquire slaves.

Comment: If the criterion to be maximized is the total number of connections, I guess that this amounts to minimizing the number of masters.